# I want to show all usernames and ids in drop-down

Tags: product

I want to show all usernames and user ids in a drop-down.
Please find my issue, where did I make a  mistake?
Here's my code:

```
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

namespace Learning\ClothingMaterial\Model\Attribute\Source;

class Material extends 
\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Get all options
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $roleName = "merchant";
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $roleModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Authorization\Model\Role');
        $userModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\User\Model\User');
        $roleModel = $roleModel->load($roleName, 'role_name');
        if($roleModel->getId()) {
            $userIds = $roleModel->getRoleUsers();

            foreach($userIds as $userId) {
                $user = $userModel->load($userId);    

                $usernames = $user->getUsername();
                $userid = $user->getId();

                print_r($user->getUsername());
                print_r($user->getId());
                echo "<br>";                                   

                if (!$this->_options) {
                    $this->_options = [
                        ['label' => __($userid - $usernames), 'value' => $userid.$usernames],
                    ];
                }

            }
        } 

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: its just show 1 id

Comment: You want to get all admin's user name?

Comment: name and id both but it shows me only one last id
Actually loop is not working here the actual problem is that

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning only one record in foreach loop as your code :

```
$this->_options = [['label' => __($userid - $usernames), 'value' => $userid.$usernames]];
```

You have to store`$this->_options` in array

```
$this->_options[] = ['label' => __($userid . '-' . $usernames), 'value' => $userid.$usernames];
```

please make sure you have define `$this->_options` variable as array in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing off Rutvee's correct answer. In response to what they said about creating a new question, that is not necassary.

> please replace below code with in your block of code :
>
> foreach($userIds as $userId) {
>       $user = $userModel->load($userId);
>       $this->_options[]= array("label"=>$user->getUsername(),"value"=>$user->getUsername());
>
> } return  $this->_options;

change:
`"label"=>$user->getUsername()`

to

`"label"=>$user->getUsername() . ' ID: ' . $user->getID()`